# How to have invoice sequence the same way as vendor bill?

Tags: odoo

The vendor bill sequence is reset every month. For example, BILL/YEAR/MONTH/xxxx (BILL/2022/01/0001). The next month would reset the sequence BILL/2022/02/0001.

However, the sequence of invoice is reset yearly, INV/2021/0001, INV/2021/0002, ... ,INV/2022/0001

So I want the invoice sequence to have the same format as vendor bill. I tried to go to Technical -> Sequence, but got no clue. I expect there would be a sequence that have prefix BILL and prefix INV but I dont see anything like that.

I see a 'Resequence' server action on the invoice, somehow it works, but I want something more flexible, the 'Resequence' I feel like you are hoping the AI figure out the pattern